# CORS on Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, cors

So I followed directions from various sources on how to enable CORS on Apache2.

Did I do this right? I put this in the domain.conf:

```
<Directory /mnt/volume1/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
</Directory>
```

But when I refresh the JSON page from a script on my desktop I'm still getting the error:  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

I dont see any access-control info at all in the headers when you look at the page with the Chrome developer tools network option.

UPDATE/ NOTES: Ive followed http://enable-cors.org/index.html to be absloutley sure I did it right and it still doesnt work properly. Is there something else wrong somewhere else? Ive got apache mod_headers installed.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you changed the config?

Comment: Yes. Several times. Reload and restart.